# update data using php and radio buttons

Tags: php, mysql, radio-button

My form does not seem to be updating. It is just ignoring the php code. I have used the same php code with different forms and never had any problems. I don't know if it because I am using radio buttons now.

```php
if (isset($_POST['submitinjury'])) {
   $query = "UPDATE injury SET neck=?,
          upperback=?,
          lowerback=?,
          chest=?,
          shoulder=?,
          arm=?,
          hand=? WHERE userid=?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssssss', $_POST['neck'], $_POST['upperback'], $_POST['lowerback'], $_POST['chest'],  $_POST['shoulder'], $_POST['arm'], $_POST['hand'],  $_SESSION['id']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    exit(header('location: home.php'));
}
```

The form. this is in the new.php file.

```html
<form action="new.php"  method="post"   >
  <table>
    <tr>
      <th style="font-size:18px" >Any previous injuries y</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Previous neck injury/surgery?</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><label class="container">Yes
            <input type="radio"  name="neck" value="yes" > 
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label></td>
      <td><label class="container">None
            <input value="none" type="radio" checked="checked" name="neck">
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>

      <td>Previous upperback injury/surgery?</td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td><label class="container">Yes
            <input type="radio"  name="upperback" value="yes" > 
            <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label></td>
      <td><label class="container">None
             <input value="none" type="radio" checked="checked" name="upperback">
             <span class="checkmark"></span>
          </label></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Previous lowerback injury/surgery?</td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td><label class="container">Yes
             <input type="radio"  name="lowerback" value="yes" > 
             <span class="checkmark"></span>
           </label></td>
       <td><label class="container">None
             <input value="none" type="radio" checked="checked" name="lowerback">
             <span class="checkmark"></span>
             </label></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td>Previous chest injury/surgery?</td>
       <td></td>
       <td></td>
       <td><label class="container">Yes
             <input type="radio"  name="chest" value="yes" > 
             <span class="checkmark"></span>
           </label></td>
       <td><label class="container">None
             <input value="none" type="radio" checked="checked" name="chest">
             <span class="checkmark"></span>
           </label></td>
     </tr>


     <tr>
       <td>Previous shoulder injury/surgery?</td>
       <td><label class="container">Both
             <input  value="both" type="radio"  name="shoulder">
             <span class="checkmark"></span>
           </label></td>
       <td><label class="container">Left
             <input  value="left" type="radio"  name="shoulder">
             <span class="checkmark"></span>
           </label></td>
       <td><label class="container">Right
             <input value="right" type="radio"  name="shoulder">
             <span class="checkmark"></span>
           </label></td>
       <td><label class="container">None
             <input value="none"  type="radio" checked="checked" name="shoulder">
             <span class="checkmark"></span>
           </label></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>Previous arm injury/surgery?</td>
        <td><label class="container">Both
              <input  value="both" type="radio"  name="arm">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label></td>
        <td><label class="container">Left
              <input  value="left" type="radio"  name="arm">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label></td>
        <td><label class="container">Right
              <input value="right" type="radio"  name="arm">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label></td>
        <td><label class="container">None
              <input type="radio" checked="checked" value="none" name="arm">
              <span  class="checkmark"></span>
            </label></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Previous hand/wrist injury/surgery?</td>
        <td><label class="container">Both
              <input  value="both" type="radio"  name="hand">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label></td>
        <td><label class="container">Left
              <input  value="left" type="radio"  name="hand">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label></td>
        <td><label class="container">Right
              <input value="right" type="radio"  name="hand">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
            </label></td>
        <td><label class="container">None
              <input type="radio" checked="checked"  value="none"  name="hand">
              <span class="checkmark"></span>
        </label></td>
      </tr>


    </table>

    <button  type="submit" name="submitinjury" >Submit</button>

</form>
```

After the button is clicked it just refresh the page and nothing gets updated in the database.

Answer (score 0):

It seems, the issue is caused by the `session`. Try adding `session_start()`.

```
if (isset($_POST['submitinjury'])) {
   session_start();
   $query = "UPDATE injury SET neck=?,
          upperback=?,
          lowerback=?,
          chest=?,
          shoulder=?,
          arm=?,
          hand=? WHERE userid=?";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'ssssssss', $_POST['neck'], $_POST['upperback'], $_POST['lowerback'], $_POST['chest'],  $_POST['shoulder'], $_POST['arm'], $_POST['hand'],  $_SESSION['id']);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    exit(header('location: home.php'));
}
```

Comment: session_start(); is added at the beginning of the page

Comment: Please add session_start() on the code, so that people will know. Also is there any error? Try adding `ini_set('display_errors', 1);` and `error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the page, to determine the error.

Comment: expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_stmt, bool given this is the error I am getting

Comment: Is your session id is integer? Then change `ssssssss` to `sssssssi`. Also make sure that `neck`, `upperback`, `lowerback`, `chest`, `shoulder`, `arm` and `hand` are strings on the data type on the database.

Comment: everything is varchar in the database

Comment: Can you try adding `mysqli_stmt_close($stmt);` after `mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);`

Comment: still the same results

Comment: Hmmm, it seems that `mysqli_prepare()` is not returning a statement. Is your `$db` returns a database connection?

Comment: Yes it is a db connection. $db = mysqli_connect('localhost', '#', '#', '#');

Comment: Did you check the value of `$_SESSION['id']` if it's matched on the database?

Comment: yes there everything is matched. I have the same type of statement on the same page and it works perfectly.        if (isset($_POST['submitextrainfo'])) {
           
          $query = "UPDATE other_parq_info SET info=?,
          other=? WHERE userid=?";
          $stmt = mysqli_prepare($db, $query);
          mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, 'sss',   $_POST['info'], $_POST['other'], $_SESSION['id']);
          mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
          exit(header('location: parq.php'));

Comment: Did you try changing `ssssssss` to `sssssssi`?

Comment: Can you check if there's an error by using `var_dump(mysqli_connect_error())` .

Comment: I just rewrote all the code and it worked. I appreciate all the help

Comment: Modify your post, and add the solution. So people may fix the issue, if the issue is the same.